# Can I implement Serializable which exists and compiled class in java(geotools)?

Tags: java, save, state, serializable, geotools

I wrote program for reading and displaying GIS shape files by GeoTools, and I want to save the state of my program.

Main class.java

```
        Project myproject=new Project();
        myproject.mapLayers=this.frame.getMapContext().getLayers();
```

Project.java

```
import org.geotools.map.MapLayer;    
public class Project implements Serializable{
    public String name;
    public  MapLayer[] mapLayers;

    public void save(String projectname){
        ReadWriteObject.writeObject(projectname+".gpr",this);
    }

    public Project load(String projectname){
        return (Project)ReadWriteObject.readObject(projectname);
    }
}
```

ReadWriteObject

```
public class ReadWriteObject {

    public static boolean writeObject(String filename, Object obj){
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

            // Write objects to file
            o.writeObject(obj);
            o.close();
            f.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Error occurred `DefaultMapLayer` is not `Serializable`.
How do I save my programs state in java?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply write out in some format (XML, JSON) the layers, styles that went into your map and then read that back in again to recreate the map. You don't actually need to store the **entire** state of the program.

Alternatively, you can [propose a change](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html) to the source code to add `Serialize` to class. Ideally you should find all of the necessary classes that will need serializing that currently don't implement `Serialize` and submit a single pull request.